# Why is wagtail image upload failing after upgrading from 4.0.2 to 4.1.2?

Tags: wagtail

Images upload fail with 403 response after upgrading wagtail from 4.0.2 to 4.1.2 via intermediate upgrades as suggested in "upgrading wagtail". Static files are on AWS S3 since the initial deployment and worked flawlessly prior to the upgrade.

// django log from server

```
Exception while resolving variable 'site_root' in template 'home/home_page.html'.
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 880, in _resolve_lookup
current = current[bit]
File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/context.py", line 83, in **getitem**
raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'site_root'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 886, in _resolve_lookup
if isinstance(current, BaseContext) and getattr(
AttributeError: type object 'RequestContext' has no attribute 'site_root'

Comment: Sorry that just isn't enough detail for us to help you. Is this in your dev environment? What do your server logs say?

Comment: This is production environment. I have even, temporarily, set DEBUG to True to see anything other than a "403 Forbidden". Nothing. In Safari developer tools, I see the URL that is being requested/posted to "admin/wagtailimages/image/add/" and the response: again, a plain 403. There is an AttributeError in django logs on the server: AttributeError: type object 'RequestContext' has no attribute 'site_root'.

Comment: OK log into your site as the root user and look at Settings -> Sites. If this is  a single site on the server, then your default site should be your production site with the correct Root Page.

Comment: cnk, thank you. That is all correctly set from the get go. The site "reads" well, ie., it is loading images and everything else; these were uploaded prior to the upgrade. I suspect that this is a permission issue, obviously, somewhere. The trick is to start the process of elimination and find out where it is. I've spent close to a week with no resolution. I might just have to rebuild a new site (copy/paste) and set up new AWS EB environment.

Comment: admin/wagtailimages/image/add is the URL that is being called; the response is 403. I am headed to wagtail source files in my virtual environment to see the view this URL is pointing to.

Comment: Could you provide the full stack trace for the AttributeError?

Comment: done. added to the original question

Comment: The `site_root` error is happening when you render a frontside template ('home/home_page.html') so is probably not related to your image upload issue. 

Can you upload documents? (I am trying to figure out if your problem is writing to S3)

Comment: Thanks. Nope, cannot upload documents either. I am thinking along the same lines--that this is likely S3 permissions issue, which I did not have before the upgrade. Debugging is fun!

Comment: Great! Now I cannot even edit pages, texts and such. Every time I save draft or publish (Admin role), 403 forbidden. This particular error is likely not S3.

Comment: The user model in the project is customized, inherits from AbstractUser. Does not explicitly have PermissionsMixin in the class hierarchy. I am wondering if this is the cause, or a cause of the 403. Creating a new project from scratch. This time, the custom user model will also inherit from PermissionsMixin, as the wagtail docs insist (but do not inherit from in their own example custom user model). We shall see.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not REALLY an answer. After spending close to a week without any resolution I rebuilt the application from scratch--fortunately a very small database so I could run a new django/wagtail app from scratch without any leftovers from the unsuccessful upgrade. At the staging stage at the moment, but images are being uploaded to S3 without a glitch. Lesson: Upgrade with caution; meanwhile, keep the stable branch running.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).